# Member management for EE 3

Tags: zoo-visitor, devdemon, member-management, ee3

Does anyone know of any member management tools that are out for EE 3?  I was hoping zoo visitor (now owned by devdemon) would be ported to EE 3, but that addon seems to have gone dark.  And profile:edit which was also purchased by someone new has gone dark as well.

I preferred those addons to using the native member manager because of the flexibility in field types you could use.  But with the lack of support behind any one member manager I may look to using the native tools to avoid any future problems.

Does anyone have any thoughts or other means they manager their website members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm trying out the Solspace User plugin: https://solspace.com/expressionengine/user.  If any other member plugins come online with EE3 I'll be sure to post it.  I'm not sure solspace does all that I need ie custom field types for members but I think it'll provide some good member management benefits over the default EE system.

I do wish EE would add some more tools and power to the member management system. Annnywho.

Answer (score 0):

Zeal smart members is new member management tool. This module is available in both EE2 and EE3. Have a look https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members